# State set method did not effect the main object - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, react-hooks

I have three components in my project, **App**, **DataTable** and **Table**.

The **App** will render a **DataTable** that contains the Table component. I just called DataTable with data and columns props in it.

```
// data sample
const tmpData = [
    {
        name: "Can",
        age: 4,
    }, {
        name: "David",
        age: 44,
    }, {
        name: "Sara",
        age: 14,
    }, {
        name: "Hani",
        age: 24,
    }
]

// main columns array
const tmpColumns = [
    {
        title: "Name",
        accessor: "name",
    }, {
        title: "Age",
        accessor: "age",
    }
]

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App" style={{background: "#f0f0f0", padding: "1rem"}}>
            <div>App Component:</div>

            <DataTable data={tmpData} columns={tmpColumns}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**DataTable** component is just for handling selection and filter actions on my table. So, it could manipulate the data and the columns. the Table will render in it and here is the code of **DataTable**.

```
function DataTable(props) {

    const [data, setData] = useState(props.data)
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState(props.columns)

    const [selection, setSelection] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        // add select columns after component mount
        handleColumnChange()
    }, [])

    // listen to selection change
    useEffect(() => {

        // selection change log, It change on each select.
        console.log(selection);
    }, [selection])

    function handleRowSelect(rowName) {

        const keyIndex = selection.indexOf(rowName);

        console.log(selection, rowName, keyIndex);

        if (keyIndex === -1)
            setSelection(preSelection => ([...preSelection, ...[rowName]]))
        else
            setSelection(preSelection => preSelection.filter(sl => sl !== rowName))

    }

    function handleColumnChange() {

        // add select column if not added already
        if (!columns.find(col => col.accessor === 'select')) {

            setColumns([
                ...[{
                    title: "Select",
                    accessor: "select",
                    // this method will execute to render checkbox on Select table
                    Cell: function (row) {

                        return <input type="checkbox"
                                      onChange={() => handleRowSelect(row.name, selection)}
                                      checked={selection.includes(row.name)}/>
                    },
                }],
                ...columns,
            ])
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="DataTable" style={{background: "#e0e0e0", padding: "1rem"}}>
            <div>Data Table:</div>

            <Table {...{data, columns}}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Table** component will render columns and suitable data for them. For each column in columns array we have an item to access data (`accessor`) or an executable method to return custom data (`Cell`) and here is its code.

```
function Table(props) {

    const [data, setData] = useState(props.data)

    return (
        <div className="Table" style={{background: "#d5d5d5", padding: "1rem"}}>
            <div>Table</div>

            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    {props.columns.map((th, key) => (
                        <th key={key}>{th.title}</th>
                    ))}
                </tr>

                {/* generating data rows */}
                {data.map((dr, key) => (
                    <tr key={key}>
                        {columns.map((col, index) => (
                            <td key={index}>
                                {
                                    // the "Cell" method has high priority than "accessor" selector
                                    (col.Cell && typeof col.Cell === "function") ?
                                        col.Cell(dr) :
                                        dr[col.accessor]
                                }
                            </td>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    )
}
```

As you saw above, to handle row selection I manipulate the columns in the **DataTable** component by adding a new column at first index of my columns array. Everything works fine for now. But, when I try to select a row, the Call methods of the select column, could not access the selection array state of my **DataTable** component. and it's my problem!

Actually, on each select, the `selection` array must update and target checkbox must check. Apparently, there is a copy of the `selection` that changes (or maybe not changes).

You also could check the whole project on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/data-table-nested-method-issue-brflg)

Comment: setSelection syntax is wrong for hooks. Set value direct no more function call

Comment: @Rikin, I don't think so! Even if I do like what you mean, the changed `selection` not accessible in my `Cell` method again.

Comment: I see it in the docs now: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables I was not aware of this callback pattern, good to know. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some fixes to your code, check it out on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/data-table-nested-method-issue-et2f3).

The idea is that you don't need to put the columns to state, instead you just need to get the columns with the selection box.

I also added a simple optimization to it by implementing **React.useMemo** to memoized the calculated columns. It will only be re-calculated when the **props.columns** and **selection state** changes.

Hope this helps! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your `tmpData` passed from `App` to `DataTable` is read-only. So by design you will not see any change your data along the way.

There're couple of ways to get it working, mostly having something to do to allow your `DataTable` to pass the change back to `App` if that happens.

Step 1, you could add one `prop` called `onRowClick` on the `DataTable`,

```
  <DataTable data={tmpData} onRowClick={row => { console.log(row) } />
```

Step 2, you need to allow your `tmpData` to change after the event. You are using hooks, so we can

```
  const [tmpData, setTmpData] = useState([sampleData])
  return (
    <DataTable data={tmpData} onRowClick={row => { 
      // use setTmpData to adjust the tmpData to get a new instance of tmpData
    } />
  )
```

Of course for things with this complexity, we normally use `useReducer` instead of `useState`, since there's definitely other things that you want to do other than selecting the row :)

Comment: But only the DataTable could manipulate the columns for filtering and selection. Also, I don't need to change tmpData as you say. I want to push all my selected rows into an array calls `selection`

Comment: in that case you need to pass `selection` and `onSelectionChange` into the `DataTable`, my friend, something has to go through the interface. Of course you don't have to pass them if you decide them are internal variable to `DataTable`. This is why sometimes referred as `unControlled` component.